# Cannot import cluster in python 2.7.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, cluster-computing

I am new to clustering, just installed the cluster package (command line: pip install cluster), and would like to import cluster. But for some reason I kept getting this:

```
>>> import cluster
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cluster/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    __version__ = resource_string('cluster','version.txt').decode('ascii').strip()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.6-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 896, in resource_string
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.6-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1305, in get_resource_string
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.6-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1426, in _get
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cluster/version.txt'
```

and my 'pip install cluster' command said

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cluster in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Is there something I could do to start using cluster? I know scipy probably has a cluster function as well, but I'd like to use the cluster package if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the [pypi page for 'cluster'](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cluster/1.2.2) says you have to import one of the kinds of clustering, as in:

```
>>> from cluster import HierarchicalClustering
>>> data = [12,34,23,32,46,96,13]
>>> cl = HierarchicalClustering(data, lambda x,y: abs(x-y))
```

or

```
>>> from cluster import KMeansClustering
>>> cl = KMeansClustering([(1,1), (2,1), (5,3), ...])
>>> clusters = cl.getclusters(2)
```

Comment: Does that fix a problem for you? Because I have that exact line and get the same error. If it does, perhaps you could explain why it helped you?